# Laravel - Install AdminLTE on existing database

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

I am using Laravel and have it fully completed my project. Now I want to install AdminLTE which I have successfully done following these steps in this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpzYy4qttTU

The end result in the video is the same end result I have.

My question is my database I have a few tables I would like to add the menu and the ability edit rows from the database in this admin section. My question is how would I do that? I can't seem to find anything online about it. How do you configure an existing database to Laravel AdminLTE?

Comment: Your question is not clear, AdminLTE and database are two different things. If you know the laravel then you can do it easily.

Comment: Basically what I am asking is in the video the end result is very basic, I am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction as to have my users table as a view in the admin panel, along with other database tables to edit.

Comment: Create a route to show users, write your logic to get users in the controller and pass the data to views. In views, to show the users listing, you can use the data tables.

Comment: Is there an example of this or documentation I can follow? @AmolRokade

Comment: follow this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation

Comment: @AmolRokade which part? And what does that have to do with AdminLTE